# github actions failure to build-and-push-docker-images

Tags: github-actions

Trying to build and push docker image for java-gradle project, Below is the action script:

```
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2     
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build        
    - name: Login to DockerHub
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
    - name: Build and push
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        context: .
        push: true
        tags: user/app:latest
```

The error lies with login to dockerhub in the script. Below is the error obtained, not sure if it is correct?
*
Run docker/login-action@v1
Error: Username and password required
*

Please help.

Comment: I have added the docker_username and password as actions-secrets.

Comment: Getting the following error:

Comment: Getting error in

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.